# Python multiprocessing socket issue

Tags: python, sockets, python-multiprocessing

I have a Base class setting a connection, and a Derived class trying to use a new connection instead. I expect the print output to be:

- create sock1
- disconnect sock1
- create sock2
- disconnect sock2         <---- but why it actually still disconnects sock1, per following output of 'laddr'

How can I fix the problem to make it working as expected?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process


class Base(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        self.sock = self._make_socket()

    def _make_socket(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect(("::1", 3482))
        sock.settimeout(1)
        print(f"new sock {sock}")
        return sock

    def disconnect(self):
        print(f"disconnect sock={self.sock}")
        self.sock.close()


class Derived(Base):
    def run(self):
        self.disconnect()
        self.sock = self._make_socket()


d = Derived()
d.start()
d.join()
d.disconnect()
```

Actual Output:

```
new sock <socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET6, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('::1', 42026, 0, 0), raddr=('::1', 3482, 0, 0)>
disconnect sock=<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET6, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('::1', 42026, 0, 0), raddr=('::1', 3482, 0, 0)>
new sock <socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET6, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('::1', 42028, 0, 0), raddr=('::1', 3482, 0, 0)>
disconnect sock=<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET6, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('::1', 42026, 0, 0), raddr=('::1', 3482, 0, 0)>
```

Comment: It reuses the local address.